# OnClick event error

Tags: javascript, onclick, html-helper

```
function setVisibility('sub1'){
   var element = document.getElementById('bt1');
   if( 'none' == element.style.display ){
       element.style.display = 'block';

   }else{
       element.style.display = 'none';

   }
   return false;
}
```

Ok so that is my javascript.. I have several buttons (sub1,sub2,sub3, and sub4) all showing different divs(bt1,bt2,bt3 and bt4)

```
<input id='bt1' type="image" src='button.png' alt="Submit" onclick="setVisibility('sub1');";>
```

That is the button itself coded into my html and then the div it shows is a simple div:

```
<div style="display: none;" id='sub1'>Text Goes Here</div>
```

But when i click the button nothing happens, I am confused as to what I am doing wrong, so if anyone would be so kind as to point out my mistake. Thanks

EDIT: The Html error deleting the extra ; didnt work, taking the ' away from sub made the 4th button appear and disappear

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Your `input` ends in `;>`, it should be `>`.

Comment: What if you fix your syntax error? You have an additionnal `;` after the `onclick` attribute. Your function signature is also wrong, arguments definitions aren't strings.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you have an invalid variable definition in your function. Instead of a string, it should define a variable that you can use target the element in question.

```
function setVisibility(subId){
 var element = document.getElementById(subId);
 ...
```

There is also a syntax error in your HTML as others noted in comments on your post, namely:

```
<input id='bt1' type="image" src='button.png' alt="Submit" onclick="setVisibility('sub1');";>
```

has an extra `;` at the end before the `>`. To be compliant, self closing elements like this should technically also end in an `/`. For example:

```
<input id='bt1' type="image" src='button.png' alt="Submit" onclick="setVisibility('sub1');" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You must declare function parameters whitout apostrophes; like this:

```
function setVisibility(sub){
  var element = document.getElementById(sub);
```

Comment: Hey, Ive tried that, And now when i click any button it hides and unhides the bt4(4th button) HELP D:

Comment: You must also fix your var 'element' to document.getElementById(sub); see my edit

Comment: so var document.getElementById(sub) = document.getElementById(sub);?? WUT

Comment: No :D, `var element = document.getElementById(sub);`

Comment: var element = document.getElementById(sub1); that is still doing nothing for me D:

Comment: Sir, just `document.getElementById(sub);`. It's the variable.

Comment: Yeah, but mine is called sub1 setVisibility is also sub1

Comment: I don't understand. It is working: http://jsbin.com/ivETATE/1/edit. The sub id comes with function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setVisibility(id){ 
   var element = document.getElementById(id);
     if( 'none' == element.style.display ){ 
         element.style.display = 'block';
     }else{ 
          element.style.display = 'none';  
     } return false;
 }
```

try this